# Create a graph in Windows 8 application

Tags: graph, windows-store-apps

I am working on a Windows 8 app which is accessing data from the database. I want to access this data and create a graph(bar and line) out of it.
If there are controls to create a graph in the app, what are they? Sample code or any links will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some more chart libs

[Getting started with free Metro (Modern UI) charts for Windows 8](http://igrali.com/2013/05/25/getting-started-with-free-metro-modern-ui-charts-windows-8/)

[OxyPlot](https://oxyplot.codeplex.com/)

[WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com)

Answer (score 1):

No chart control is included in standard controls, you will have to use 3rd party controls :

- Telerik chart control, it's working great, it's not free though, 
  http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-8/controls/chart.aspx
- http://modernuitoolkit.codeplex.com/ - free
- http://www.visifire.com/blog/2012/09/24/windows-8-metro-charts/ - not free
- http://www.visiblox.com/visibloxcharts-for-winrt - not free